# How tomcat allows to specify comma separated list of CORS origins?

Tags: tomcat, cors, tomcat9

Tomcat documentation here [Link](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-10.0-doc/config/filter.html#CORS_Filter) specifies that a comma separated list is acceptable

```
cors.allowed.origins - A list of origins that are allowed to access the resource. A * can be specified to enable access to resource from any origin. Otherwise,an allow list of comma separated origins can be provided. Eg: https://www.w3.org, https://www.apache.org. Defaults: The empty String. (No origin is allowed to access the resource).
```

Whereas link [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin) specifies that only one origin is allowed to be specified

```
<origin>
Specifies an origin. Only a single origin can be specified. If the server supports clients from multiple origins, it must return the origin for the specific client making the request.
```

How is tomcat managing to specify multiple origins when as per specification only one origin is allowed?